# Shenzhen IO character differences

Tags: translation

The video game, Shenzhen IO seems to have different spellings of the fictitious company's name in Chineese.

The game's store page uses 深圳龙腾科技有限公司, while the game's manual uses:

[image]

The first character looks a bit different. Is this just a different font, or is it a different character?

In case your stack exchange font is different to mine, the game web page looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is mostly a font display difference, so it’ll help others to answer your question if you include a screenshot of what you see on your computer/screen.

Comment: @droooze, the image at the bottom of the post is what I see on my screen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-variant

Comment: For human, it's just different font. For computer, it may be and likely to be, but actually don't have to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The first character looks a bit different. Is this just a different font, or is it a different character?**

Unicode treats them with the same codepoint (U+6DF1), so it's the same character according to digital standards.

The difference in appearance is usually due to fonts, which adhere to different standards across the regions which use Chinese characters.

[image]

Mainland Chinese standards use a「八」shape, while other regions usually use a「儿」shape. If you're seeing「儿」then your fonts are not designed according to the Mainland Chinese standard.

> We now have super-families of fonts like [Noto CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts#CJK) which accommodate for both differences in orthography ([character variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Chinese_character)) and (minor) differences in regional shapes, so you can get (for example) a text which has Simplified Chinese but with the non-Simplified characters as Korean shapes.
>
> The exact font you're using to display those characters is Noto Sans CJK JP.
>
> [image]
>
> Minor differences exist in all standards; your browser thinks the text language is Japanese, or defaults it to Japanese.

If you're learning Chinese characters not specifically from Mainland China, write it with「儿」.

---

> For reference, that component was originally「穴」, which depicts a [cave dwelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaodong) (**窯洞**). The two strokes under「宀」was an abstract depiction of ventilation passages or air currents.
>
> ## <kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [新甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)3.83</kbd>
>
> The structure of「深」has changed like the following over the years:
>
> ## <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze_inscription)・[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
> [image][image]
> 乖伯歸夆簋「罙」
> [集成4331](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4331&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>楚
> 簡
> [image]
> [上(1)・孔](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・2</kbd>
> 　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[雜](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)15</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> As can be seen,「八」or「儿」is just an approximation of a shape, and neither character actually features as a component in「深」. [*Shuowen*'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) description
>
> > 「穴」，土室也。从「宀」，「八」聲。
> >
> > 「穴」([Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)) [Old Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese): **/*[ɢ]ʷˤi[t]/**), earthen dwelling; from semantic「宀」(*building*) and phonetic「八」(**/*pˤret/**).
>
> is very likely to be incorrect.
>
> ---
>
> ## References:
>
> - 季旭昇《說文新證》
> - 李學勤《字源》
> - [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
> - [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)